# Filtering between specific values creating sublists

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have this list:

```
List<String> names= Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Tom", "louis", "martha", "Tom", "john", "Carol", "Tom", "Simon"});
```

I want to create three different lists where I put the values between Tom word:

```
"Tom", "louis", "martha";
"Tom", "john", "Carol";
"Tom", "Simon"
```

I was doing with indexes in a traditional way

My way was just;

```
List<Integer> positionsWithTom = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i<names.size; i++){
...
positionsWithTom = [0,3,6]
}
```

and then put the values between in different lists

There is not a much elegant by doing this, maybe  with stream filtering somehow?

Comment: I don’t have a Java stream API syntax solution handy but your instinct is correct: this *can* in principle be done elegantly using streams. Firstly, you need to calculate the cumulative count of `"Tom"` elements; for your example this will give you the sequence 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3. You can use these numbers as classes for the `groupingBy` collector. (This can all be done in a single pass.)

Comment: I posted both a stream and non stream solution.  I prefer the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this easily lends itself to streams.  Nor would a stream approach be any more clear in expressing the problem statement than a simple loop.

As long as you don't care what order the sublists are in, it is pretty straight forward using `List.lastIndexOf` and a `while loop`.  Note that since this chews up the original list and the fact that these sublists don't overlap, there is no chance of the sublists being altered by changes to the original list or by each other (unless a reference to the original exists). But one can always pass the `sublist` as an argument to the `ArrayList` constructor if this is a concern.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Tom", "louis",
        "martha", "Tom", "john", "Carol", "Tom", "Simon"));

List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    
int start;
while ((start = names.lastIndexOf("Tom")) >= 0) {
    ists.add(names.subList(start, names.size()));
    names = names.subList(0, start);
}
    
lists.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
[Tom, Simon]
[Tom, john, Carol]
[Tom, louis, martha]
```

Note that the order can be reversed by specifying an index of `0` in the `add` method.  But that can be expensive for `ArrayLists` due to the copying.  A `LinkedList` would alleviate that expense for a bit of overhead.

**And just for completion, here is my stream solution.**

- first, stream the names in successive `sublists` based on where `Tom` is located. So the first list contains all the names, the second, all but the last `"Tom"` grouping, and so forth.
- Then for each of those sublists, pick off the last sublist starting with `Tom` from the end.
- and put the lists in a collection.

```
List<List<String>> result = Stream.iterate(
            names,
            n -> n.size() > 0 && n.lastIndexOf("Tom") >= 0,
            n -> n.subList(0, n.lastIndexOf("Tom")))
        .map(n -> n.subList(n.lastIndexOf("Tom"), n.size()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
[Tom, Simon]
[Tom, john, Carol]
[Tom, louis, martha]
```

I still prefer the while loop solution as I think it is cleaner and more succinct.  Someone more proficient in streams could probably do it better.

Answer (score 1):

First I collected the indexes of elements (`[0, 3, 6]`) that have the value `"Tom"` to the `tomindex` list. Then I used [subList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) method.

This part:

```
j == tomindex.size() - 1 ? names.subList(tomindex.get(j), names.size())
                        : names.subList(tomindex.get(j), tomindex.get(j + 1))
```

is not to miss the last one. Last element of `tomindex` is `6` and we need to fetch values between the indexes `6` and `8` so we use `names.size()` at the end.

Try this:

```
List<Integer> tomindex = IntStream.range(0, names.size()).filter(i -> names.get(i).equals("Tom")).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

Collection<List<String>> subLists = IntStream.range(0, tomindex.size())
        .mapToObj(j -> j == tomindex.size() - 1 ? names.subList(tomindex.get(j), names.size())
                : names.subList(tomindex.get(j), tomindex.get(j + 1)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(subLists);
```

Output:

```
[[Tom, louis, martha], [Tom, john, Carol], [Tom, Simon]]
```